# Programmatically enforced rules for tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-tips

Are there programmatically enforced rules for tags?

In particular it's mostly (29 out of 30?) the case that the [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and the tag [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) do not belong on the same question. Unity the company called their feature to export a Unity project to HTML/JavaScript as "*export to WebGL*" or making a "WebGL build" when in reality they are exporting to HTML+JavaScript. Nearly all the questions tagged as [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) and [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) have absolutely nothing to do with actual WebGL and instead being C# question or questions about Unity features that that path doesn't support like reading files, networking, and other things that have nothing to do with WebGL.

I fix most of them by changing [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) to [unity-webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-webgl) (except if it's actually appropriate of course) but it's extremely annoying and I'm wondering if the process could be helped with some levels of confirmation. For example when a user tries to post with both tags suggest they probably mean [unity-webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-webgl) and double check.